# Filtering broadcast in the observer pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns

A senior programmer wants to use my observer pattern class for updating different object when a *subject changes.* Now The subject will change by receiving messages with different semantics. Let say that there are two types of messages, mA and mB and I have three observers oX, oY, and oZ.

- oX wants to know about mA
- oY wants to know about mB
- oZ wants to know about mA and mB

He is telling me to have some logic (if-else) in the subject side saying that

- if mA arrives,  send it to oX and oZ
- if mB arrives, send it to oY and oZ

To me, that feels fishy because it makes the subject to know about the concrete types of  its observers (I'm using an abstract class to broadcast to the observers)

It feels more like a router aware of the destination than a broadcast to whomever is interesting on listening. Since I'm a junior programmer, I didn't object but it feels like its breaking the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. That knowledge would have to be in some kind of dispatcher. That could range from super simple, in which case it is basically a Mediator, to something more complex, in which case you want to pull down the Doug Schmidt books and have a look at some of his solutions (e.g. Reactor or Proactor).

The other option is to support different listeners. For instance, I could have a lifecycle listener for a wizard, in which case, I will trigger on onStart(), onNext() and onFinish(). Then there is no logic, the other side just pays attention to the things that it's interested in, or triggers its behaviors based on the remote event state.

You can always turn Observer inside out by using Command. If someone is saying to you 'hey, when x happens, if y is true, do z,' you can have a command that has that if y do z inside and you are just triggering it when x happens (by calling execute()).

Comment: I thought about using different listeners, but a Command seems a simple solution as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more details I would tend to agree with you. Especially if the components are all in the same memory space, just broadcast the message and let the observers sort out what they are interseted in. But there may be more to the specific problem than you realize. Try to understand why he wants it this way. There are often hidden bits of history on a project that drive seemingly odd decisions.

Answer (score 0):

you could modify the signature of the notify () method which is used by subject to notify the observers. You can have all your event types in an enum and then can use it as a parameter of the notif (EventType type) and then in each observer you can write a simple if starement and do te filtering.

Suppose ObserveTemp and ObserveHumidity are two observers for a subject Room , then if tempreature changes you can do 
observer.notify (Event_Temp) and in case of humidity change you can do notify (Event_Humidity). In Observers when you provide implementation for notify method you could modify the signature of the notify () method which is used by subject to notify the observers. You can have all your event types in an enum and then can use it as a parameter of the notif (EventType type) and then in each observer you can write a simple if starement and do te filtering.

Suppose ObserveTemp and ObserveHumidity are two observers for a subject Room , then if tempreature changes you can do 
observer.notify (Event_Temp) and in case of humidity change you can do notify (Event_Humidity). In ObserveTemp when you provide implementation for notify method you can do like below.

```
public void notify (Event_Type type)    {
    if (type == Event_temp){
        //do processing...
    }
}
```

hope it helps, here subject need not know about which concete classes are alactually implementing the Observer.